# jQuery UI autocomplete with json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My autocomplete input field does not work and I can't find why. I'm using an external JSON file which looks like that:

```
{
  "nodes": [
  {"id": "nt", "data": {
        "class": "date",
        "label": "Expositions New Tendencies",
        "tooltip": "New Tendencies Exhibition",
        "content": "Ceci est une visualisation de donnée concernant les différentes expositions sous le nom de 'New Tendencies', et regroupe les différents artistes, et leurs oeuvres. Pour parcourir la visualisation, cliquez sur les différents noeuds !",
        "graphicFillColor": "#fff",
        "graphicSize": 80,
        "labelFontSize": 18,
        "labelFontWeight": "regular",
        "labelPosition": "right"
    }}],

 "edges": [   
  {"source": "nt1", "target": "AdrianMarc"}
]}
```

So for clarity, I went for a multiple dimension array. Here is my JavaScript file with the auto complete

```js
$(function() {
    $('#recherche').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "feature-tour.json",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: request,
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        console.log(item.nodes.id);
                        return(item.nodes.id)
                    }));
                }
            }); 
        },  
        minLength: 0
    });
});
```

and the HTML input :

```html
<input type="text" id="recherche" placeholder="→ Rechercher un artiste"/>
```

I would like to display the label of a nodes inside the autocomplete input, if someone could help me to access to the label of a node. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your nodes are exposed as a `nodes` key in your file, so you should iterate over `data.nodes`, not `data` :

   ```
   success: function(data) {
       var filtered = $.map(data.nodes, function(item) {
       // ...
       });
       response(filtered);
   }
   ```
2. You probably want to feed your `response` callback [an array of objects with `label` and `value` properties](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) :

   ```
   success: function(data) {
       var filtered = $.map(data.nodes, function(item) {
           return {
               label: item.data.label,
               value: item.id
           };
       });
       response(filtered);
   }
   ```
3. Don't forget you will have to do the filtering yourself either server side or client side before calling the callback. Here's an example where the labels must contain the query (case insensitive)

   ```
   success: function(data) {
       var query = request.term.toLowerCase(),
           filtered;

       filtered = $.grep(data.nodes, function(item) {
           return item.data.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) !==-1 ;
       });

       filtered = $.map(filtered, function(item) {
           return {
               label: item.data.label,
               value: item.id
           };
       });

       response(filtered);
   }
   ```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/fh93xue4/2/

Comment: Thank you for the help @nikoshr . But I still have one more question, do I have to put the content of my JSON file into a `var`or not ? Because if my autocomple's `source`is a function which will filter the request, I can't use my JSON file anymore ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, your file content is available in your `success` callback via the `data` argument. If you're referring to the way I set things up in my Fiddle, it's just a demo and you don't have to copy the content of your file in your app. Basically, just replace your callback and you should be OK.

Comment: I figured it out right after asking my question. Thank you for the help once again.

Comment: Well,i can't find a way to make the filter working, I tried to do something based on the link you provide but still no update while typing. Do I have to do something with `data`of `$.ajax()`? Use a `request.term`I presume, but I don't understand how to check if the term is inside the id/label of my JSON file.